# Remaing keys in keychain access

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain

I recently revoked my certificate on apple.developer account. After that I downloaded the new one, and install it in Keychain Access. When I tried to build a app in Xcode 3.2.6 or 4.2, I was getting an error message explaining that I have two certificates with the same reference. So I deleted the one I had revoked. Then the build did not encounter any problem.

But each time I restart my computer, the deleted key appears again and I still need to delete it before to build.

Does someone knows how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I noticed that it was each time that I was opening Xcode 4.2 that the key was duplicated. I had to uninstall Xcode 3.2.6 to return back to normal.